# Testing multiple requests Promise.all with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I couldn't find any documentation related to how to test several requests (Promise.all) with React Testing Library.
I have a component loads data from 4 urls by Promise.all. According the [React Testing Library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro), when there is one request, a server is set by `setupServer`. What about 4 requests? Shall I setup 4 servers? How to test that?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CalculateFee from './CalculateFee';

function Commissions() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [feeCashIn, setFeeCashIn] = useState(null);
    const [feeCashOutNatural, setFeeCashOutNatural] = useState(null);
    const [feeCashOutLegal, setFeeCashOutLegal] = useState(null);  

    useEffect(() => {
        const url1 = "http://...";
        const url2 = "https://...";
        const url3 = "https://...";
        const url4 = "https://...";

        const promise1 = axios.get(url1).then(response => {
            setUsers(response);
        });
        const promise2 = axios.get(url2).then(response => {
            setFeeCashIn(response);
        });
        const promise3 = axios.get(url3).then(response => {
            setFeeCashOutNatural(response);
        });
        const promise4 = axios.get(url4).then(response => {
            setFeeCashOutLegal(response);
        });

        Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4]).then(values => {
            return values;
          }).catch(error => {
            setError(error);
          })
    }, []);

    if (error) return <h3>An error happened: {error.message}</h3>
    
    let usersArr = [];
    if (users.length !== 0) {
        usersArr = Object.values(users)[0];
    }

    return(
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Id:</th>
                    <th>Date:</th>
                    <th>Fee EUR:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {((usersArr.length > 0) && feeCashIn && feeCashOutNatural && feeCashOutLegal) ?
                    usersArr.map((user, i) => {
                        return <CalculateFee />
                }) : 
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan={2}>Loading...</td>
                </tr>}                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

export default Commissions;
```

Comment: Note that React Testing Library doesn't actually handle HTTP requests. The linked example is using https://github.com/mswjs/msw So you might look for "msw setupServer multiple handlers" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple handlers to `setupServer()`. [[msw docs]](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node)

The linked RTL docs example would look like this:

```js
const server = setupServer(
  rest.get('https://url1', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({greeting: 'response 1'}))
  }),
  rest.get('http://url2', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({data: 'response 2'}))
  }),
  rest.get('https://url3', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({whatever: 'res 3'}))
  })
)
```

Comment: That should help. I'll try now. Thank you very much!

Comment: And how to pass those handlers as parameters to the component? 
render(<Commissions url1="/commissions" url2="/data" url3="/data" url4="/data" />)

Comment: @Azu Don't follow the RTL example as is. It passes the URL for better visibility for the sake of example. In your case you fetch some URLs in your component and in your tests you should have the handlers that reference those URLs. You don't have to pass the URL to the component.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuriy. You answered my question however the test doesn't pass:) That is going to be difficult.